# Trying to loop <div> from sql array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I'm trying to loop this

```
<div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <div class="caption-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/portfolio/cabin.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
```

two or three times, according to my mysql_num_rows.

> #portofolioModal1

will be changed to the jenis_mbl row from my table

> cabin.png

will be changed to the foto_mbl from my table too.
so i tried like this.

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from tbmobil group by jenis_mbl");
        $jumlah=mysql_num_rows($result);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
        echo '<div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="'.$row['jenis_mbl'].'" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <div class="caption-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/portfolio/'.$row['foto_mbl'].'" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                </div>';
        }
```

but i never get the result. it only shown

> '; } mysql_close(); ?>

then a link

> '.$row['jenis_mbl'].'

Comment: Is it a php file, are you running it on a web-server, do you have an opening php tag, etc.?

Comment: I think the problem refers to another part of code. Please share all your code.

Comment: please, add a clear example of the result you get.

Comment: show us the mysql_num_rows function you are using

Comment: yes, its on a web-server.